# ArgumentError storing and retrieving pointer in class in Boost.Python: wrong type

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I'm using Boost.Python 1.54 on Windows with MSVC2010, and I have a problem storing a pointer to one class in a second class from python, and retrieving it.  It seems to change data type somehow.

Here's my classes:

```
typedef unsigned int uint_t;

struct classA {
  int intval;
  unsigned int bitfield_member:1;
};

struct Collection {
  classA * class_a_ptr;
};
```

and here's how I expose them to python (some of this code was originally autogenerated by Py++, but I've hand-edited it since then):

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python/return_value_policy.hpp>
#include <boost/python/manage_new_object.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

struct Collection_wrapper : Collection, bp::wrapper< Collection > {

    Collection_wrapper(Collection const & arg )
    : Collection( arg )
      , bp::wrapper< Collection >(){
        // copy constructor

    }

    Collection_wrapper()
    : Collection()
      , bp::wrapper< Collection >(){
        // null constructor

    }

    static ::classA * get_class_a_ptr(Collection const & inst ){
        return inst.class_a_ptr;
    }

    static void set_class_a_ptr( Collection & inst, ::classA * new_value ){
        inst.class_a_ptr = new_value;
    }
};

struct classA_wrapper : classA, bp::wrapper< classA > {

    classA_wrapper(classA const & arg )
    : classA( arg )
      , bp::wrapper< classA >(){
        // copy constructor

    }

    classA_wrapper()
    : classA()
      , bp::wrapper< classA >(){
        // null constructor

    }

    ::uint_t get_bitfield_member() const {
        return bitfield_member;
    }

    void set_bitfield_member( ::uint_t new_value ){
        bitfield_member = new_value;
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(render_lib_ext)

{
  using namespace bp;

    { //::Collection
        typedef bp::class_< Collection_wrapper > Collection_exposer_t;
        Collection_exposer_t Collection_exposer = Collection_exposer_t( "Collection" );
        bp::scope Collection_scope( Collection_exposer );
    // original version, fails
    Collection_exposer.add_property( "class_a_ptr"
                    , bp::make_function( (::classA * (*)( ::Collection const & ))(&Collection_wrapper::get_class_a_ptr), bp::return_internal_reference< >() )
                    , bp::make_function( (void (*)( ::Collection &,::classA * ))(&Collection_wrapper::set_class_a_ptr), bp::with_custodian_and_ward_postcall< 1, 2 >() ) );
    }

  { //::classA
    typedef bp::class_< classA_wrapper > classA_exposer_t;
    classA_exposer_t classA_exposer = classA_exposer_t( "classA" );
    bp::scope classA_scope( classA_exposer );
    classA_exposer.def_readwrite( "intval", &classA::intval );
    classA_exposer.add_property( "bitfield_member"
                   , (::uint_t ( classA_wrapper::* )(  ) const)(&classA_wrapper::get_bitfield_member)
                   , (void ( classA_wrapper::* )( ::uint_t ) )(&classA_wrapper::set_bitfield_member) );
  }
}
```

and here's the python test to exercise it:

```
import unittest
import render_lib_ext as RL

class TestRenderLib(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_globals(self):
        coll=RL.Collection()
        g = RL.classA()
        g.intval=9801;
        self.assertEqual(9801, g.intval)
        coll.class_a_ptr = g # store pointer in collection
        geg = coll.class_a_ptr # retrieve it
        self.assertEqual(0, g.bitfield_member) # works
        self.assertEqual(0, geg.bitfield_member) # fails with ArgumentError (type error)
        self.assertEqual(9801, geg.intval)    # fails!  Is it not the same object?
```

It fails with this error on the first "fails" line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 18, in test_globals
    self.assertEqual(0, geg.bitfield_member) # fails with ArgumentError (type error)
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    None.None(classA)
did not match C++ signature:
    None(struct classA_wrapper {lvalue})
```

which seems odd to me since classA_wrapper extends classA.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a different way to do this?  I'm pretty experienced in python and c++, but this is my first foray into Boost.Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functors exposed to the `bitfield_member` property on `classA` needs to explicitly accept the instance on which they operate.  It is equivalent to the [`property()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) method in Python, where *fget* and *fset* accept the `self` argument.  Therefore, change the `bitfield_member` getter and setter functions to be static and accept `classA&` as their first argument.

```cpp
// ...

struct classA_wrapper: ...
{
  // ...

  static ::uint_t get_bitfield_member(classA& self)
  {
    return self.bitfield_member;
  }

  static void set_bitfield_member(classA& self, ::uint_t new_value)
  {
    self.bitfield_member = new_value;
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(...)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // ...

  python::class_< classA_wrapper >("classA")
    .def_readwrite("intval", &classA::intval)
    .add_property("bitfield_member",
                  &classA_wrapper::get_bitfield_member,
                  &classA_wrapper::set_bitfield_member)
    ;
  }
}
```

Although `get_bitfield_member` and `set_bitfield_member` are member functions in the original code, the Python `classA` object returned from `class_a_ptr` does not appear to have been completely initialized its underlying C++ type.  This may be the result of undefined behavior within the Boost.Python API.

The problem does not surface elsewhere, because:

- `Collection.class_a_ptr` property's *fget* and *fset* explicitly accepts the instance argument.
- `classA.intval` property uses `def_readwrite`, which will implicitly create *fget* and *fset* that accepts the instance via [`make_getter/make_setter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/v2/data_members.html#introduction).

---

Here is a complete example based on the original code:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

typedef unsigned int uint_t;

struct classA
{
  int intval;
  unsigned int bitfield_member:1;
};

struct Collection
{
  classA * class_a_ptr;
};

namespace python = boost::python;

struct Collection_wrapper
  : Collection, python::wrapper<Collection>
{
  Collection_wrapper() {}

  Collection_wrapper(const Collection& self)
    : Collection(self)
  {}  

  static ::classA* get_class_a_ptr(const Collection& self)
  {
    return self.class_a_ptr;
  }

  static void set_class_a_ptr(Collection& self, ::classA * new_value)
  {
    self.class_a_ptr = new_value;
  }
};

struct classA_wrapper
  : classA, python::wrapper<classA>
{
  classA_wrapper() {}

  classA_wrapper(const classA& self)
    : classA(self)
  {}  

  static ::uint_t get_bitfield_member(const classA& self)
  {
    return self.bitfield_member;
  }

  static void set_bitfield_member(classA& self, ::uint_t new_value)
  {
    self.bitfield_member = new_value;
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  python::class_<Collection_wrapper>("Collection")
    .add_property("class_a_ptr",
      python::make_function(&Collection_wrapper::get_class_a_ptr,
                            python::return_internal_reference<>()),
      python::make_function(&Collection_wrapper::set_class_a_ptr,
                            python::with_custodian_and_ward_postcall<1, 2>()))
    ;

  python::class_<classA_wrapper>("classA")
    .def_readwrite("intval", &classA::intval)
    .add_property("bitfield_member",
                  &classA_wrapper::get_bitfield_member,
                  &classA_wrapper::set_bitfield_member)
    ;
}
```

And its usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> collection = example.Collection()
>>> a = example.classA()
>>> a.intval = 9801
>>> print a.intval
9801
>>> collection.class_a_ptr = a
>>> same_a = collection.class_a_ptr
>>> a.bitfield_member = 0
>>> print a.bitfield_member
0
>>> print same_a.bitfield_member
0
>>> same_a.bitfield_member = 1
>>> print a.bitfield_member
1
>>> print same_a.bitfield_member
1
```

Comment: Thanks!  This seems exactly right.  In my case, I had too many actual members to hand-edit all the Py++-generated accessors, so instead I made `get_class_a_ptr` return a `classA_wrapper *` instead of `classA *`, and that also seems to work.